# How do I make a double jump script?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.DoubleJumpEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    local CD = plr:WaitForChild("hasDJump")
    if CD.Value == true then
        CD.Value = false
        print("doublejump")
        plr:WaitForChild("hasDJump").Value = false
        local humanoid = plr.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        humanoid:ChangeState(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Jumping)
        while humanoid.FloorMaterial == Enum.Material.Air do
            task.wait(0.01)
        end
        CD.Value = true
    end
end)
```

this is the code but the `humanoid:ChangeState(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Jumping)` doesn't work? I looked at all tutorials and all use this it just doesn't work for me

So I expected it to just jump but it does nothing, no error and i put a print to check and everything works accordingly...